# The seaborn styles shipped by Matplotlib are deprecated since 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, deprecation-warning

> The seaborn styles shipped by Matplotlib are deprecated since 3.6,
> as they no longer correspond to the styles shipped by seaborn.
> However, they will remain available as 'seaborn-v0_8-<style>'. Alternatively, directly use the seaborn API instead.

I have tried this:

```
# use seaborn style
plt.style.use("seaborn")
```

but it is deprecated, and I want to remove this warning when I use the cmd in windows

Comment: For the reference, this is the [PR 22317](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/22317) which implemented the change (along with links to relevant issues). Extra arguments are given in [rejected issue 24256](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24256) asking to reconsider the name change.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This warning is telling you that seaborn styles in matplotlib do not match current seaborn styles, since the latest have been updated.

This is why you should set the style as follow:

```
plt.style.use("seaborn-v0_8")
```

You can specify a theme by replacing `<style>` with one the following:

- bright
- colorblind
- dark
- dark-palette
- darkgrid
- deep
- muted
- notebook
- paper
- pastel
- poster
- talk
- ticks
- white
- whitegrid

Just like this:

```
plt.style.use("seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid")
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the latest seaborn styles, use their [library](https://pypi.org/project/seaborn/) directly.

Edit: adding missing themes for completeness.

Comment: Starting with MPL 3.8, no warning is issued anymore. Only `seaborn-v0_8-<style>` works. You'll get an error when using `seaborn-<style>`.  See [mpl release note](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.8.0.html#removal-of-deprecated-apis).

Answer (score 4):

See valid seaborn styles and other styles in matplotlib:
Fire up the REPL for Python using your cmd search for the available seaborn styles

```
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.style.available
```

Sample Output

```
['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', '_mpl-gallery', '_mpl-gallery-nogrid', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn-v0_8', 'seaborn-v0_8-bright', 'seaborn-v0_8-colorblind', 'seaborn-v0_8-dark', 'seaborn-v0_8-dark-palette', ...]
```

Now you can use plt.style.use(seaborn-style of your choice)
Source: From Python Crash Course [Eric Matthes]

Comment: Great! I complemented my answer with the missing themes since the question is becoming quite popular.