# Create a Seaborn style histogram / kernel density plot using the actual density function

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I really like to the look of [Seaborn's KDE plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html):

[image]

I was wondering how can I replicate this for line plot.
In my case I actually have the function to generate the density instead of samples of the data.
So assuming I have the data in a data frame:

1. `x` - The value of `x` per sample.
2. `y` - The value of the density function at `y`.
3. `μσ` - Categorical variable to group data from the same density (In the code, I use the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution).

I can use Seaborn's `lineplot` to get what I want without the area below the curve as in the image above.

I'm after achieving the look as above for the data I have.
Is there a way to replicate this theme, area under the curve included, for `lineplot`?

The code below shows what I got so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd

from scipy.stats import norm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


num_grid_pts  = 1000
val_μ         = [0, -1, 1, 0]
val_σ         = [1, 2, 3, 4]

num_var = len(val_μ) # variations

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num_grid_pts)
P = np.zeros((num_grid_pts, num_var)) # PDF

μσ = [f'μ = {μ}, σ = {σ}' for μ, σ in zip(val_μ, val_σ)]

for ii, (μ, σ) in enumerate(zip(val_μ, val_σ)):
  randVar  = norm(μ, σ)
  P[:, ii] = randVar.pdf(x)

df_P = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': np.tile(x, num_var), 'PDF': P.flatten('F'), 'μσ': np.repeat(μσ, len(x))})

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
sns.lineplot(data=df_P, x='x', y='PDF', hue='μσ', ax=ax)
plot_lines = ax.get_lines()
for ii in range(num_var):
  ax.fill_between(x=plot_lines[ii].get_xdata(), y1=plot_lines[ii].get_ydata(), alpha=0.25, color=plot_lines[ii].get_color())
ax.set_title(f'Normal Distribution')
ax.set_xlabel(f'Value')
ax.set_ylabel(f'Probability')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I used the `lineplot` to create the lines and then created the fills. But this is a hack, I was wondering if I can do it more naturally within Seaborn.

Comment: Please let me know what to improve in the question instead of `-1`.

Comment: maybe it's missing the code to reproduce the example?

Comment: @mozway, It is not my example, I just posted the result I want from the documentation of Seaborn. The problem is this look is for KDE while I want it for regular line plot.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Or are you looking for a freelancer?

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation, I'd say that I'm looking for understanding how does Seaborn achieve that look in order to replicate it. Just like other question may ask how to draw a rectangle.

Comment: Well, at StackOverflow you are supposed to create reproducible example code and data that achieves something close to your desired result, and where you indicate what is still missing.  As stated, your post is too general, leaving too much guessing to know what you're after.

Comment: @JohanC, I added some code.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to manually play with the elements do so using the [area object](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Area.html):

```py
(
    so.Plot(healthexp, "Year", "Spending_USD", color="Country")
    .add(so.Area(alpha=.7), so.Stack())
)
```

The result is:

[image]

Yet for some reason the example code doesn't work.

What I did was using Seabron's `lineplot()` and then manually add `fill_between()` polygon:

```py
ax = sns.lineplot(data=data_frame, x='data_x', y='data_y', hue='data_color')
plot_lines = ax.get_lines()
for i in range(num_unique_colors):
  ax.fill_between(x=plot_lines[i].get_xdata(), y1=plot_lines[i].get_ydata(), alpha=0.25, color=plot_lines[i].get_color())
```

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.plot.area can be done directly from the DataFrame,

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, Indeed. Can I get the theming of Seaborn?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74716259/7758804