# Matplotlib - Seaborn-whitegrid is not a valid package style

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using ADTK for anomaly detection and matplotlib for the visualization, but I am getting errors trying to run my program. This is my code and I run using python3

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

 
from adtk.data import validate_series
from adtk.visualization import plot
from adtk.detector import PersistAD

data = pd.read_csv('SQL_bytes_sent_ferdig.csv', index_col="time", parse_dates=True)
# Convert the index to a DatetimeIndex explicitly if it's not already
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, utc=True)

# Add 1 hour to the index
data.index = data.index + pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
data_valid = validate_series(data)


persist_ad = PersistAD(c=3.0, side='positive')
anomalies = persist_ad.fit_detect(data_valid)

plot(data_valid, anomaly=anomalies, ts_linewidth=1, ts_markersize=3, anomaly_markersize=3, anomaly_color='red', anomaly_tag="marker");
```

Running this gives the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/ad/sql_ad.py:1: DeprecationWarning:
Pyarrow will become a required dependency of pandas in the next major release of pandas (pandas 3.0),
(to allow more performant data types, such as the Arrow string type, and better interoperability with other libraries)
but was not found to be installed on your system.
If this would cause problems for you,
please provide us feedback at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54466

  import pandas as pd
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adtk/detector/_detector_1d.py:270: FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas. Value 'nan' has dtype incompatible with bool, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
  predicted[s.isna()] = np.nan
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adtk/detector/_detector_1d.py:141: FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas. Value 'nan' has dtype incompatible with bool, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
  predicted[s.isna()] = np.nan
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adtk/aggregator/_aggregator.py:211: FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas. Value 'nan' has dtype incompatible with bool, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
  predicted[predicted & lists.isna().any(axis=1)] = float("nan")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/style/core.py", line 137, in use
    style = _rc_params_in_file(style)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 866, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 843, in _open_file_or_url
    with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'seaborn-whitegrid'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/ad/sql_ad.py", line 22, in <module>
    plot(data_valid, anomaly=anomalies, ts_linewidth=1, ts_markersize=3, anomaly_markersize=3, anomaly_color='red', anomaly_tag="marker");
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adtk/visualization/_visualization.py", line 201, in plot
    plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/style/core.py", line 139, in use
    raise OSError(
OSError: 'seaborn-whitegrid' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in `style.available`)
```

I have looked into other posts with similar problems and tried to specify which style to use in my code, where I have the following styles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook'])
print(plt.style.available)
```

Gives:

```
['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', '_mpl-gallery', '_mpl-gallery-nogrid', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn-v0_8', 'seaborn-v0_8-bright', 'seaborn-v0_8-colorblind', 'seaborn-v0_8-dark', 'seaborn-v0_8-dark-palette', 'seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid', 'seaborn-v0_8-deep', 'seaborn-v0_8-muted', 'seaborn-v0_8-notebook', 'seaborn-v0_8-paper', 'seaborn-v0_8-pastel', 'seaborn-v0_8-poster', 'seaborn-v0_8-talk', 'seaborn-v0_8-ticks', 'seaborn-v0_8-white', 'seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid', 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

But none of them changes the error. Running it in Jupytor Notebook it works and I dont even have to specify which plot to use. I tried installing seaborn using pip but still nothing works.

Comment: @JohanC 
"Upgrading atdk": I just tried it and it says that adtk is already up to date. 
"Installing seaborn": ```Collecting seaborn
  Downloading seaborn-0.13.2-py3-none-any.whl (294 kB)```
It looks like I managed to download it, yet comparing the errors prior to installing it and after, nothing changes. Still getting the same error

Comment: It seems to be a bug in adtk (see [source code](https://github.com/odnura/adtk/blob/9a7820209418db4ab956d3e785b279471924b7b0/src/adtk/visualization/_visualization.py#L201)) It should actually be `seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid` as mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716259/the-seaborn-styles-shipped-by-matplotlib-are-deprecated-since-3-6/74716639#74716639)

Comment: Indeed since MPL 3.8, support for `seaborn-<style>` has been dropped: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.8.0.html#removal-of-deprecated-apis

Comment: What I have tried:

Changing the source code of adtk visualization to be: ```seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid``` but still getting the same error. I changed it back to the original after seeing it did not have any effect.

As I have mentioned, setting the style to any of the available styles still does not change the error.

Comment: I doubt you'd get the same error if you modify the code at `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/adtk/visualization/_visualization.py` (line 201). It might be cleaner to downgrade to mpl 3.7 until the next adtk update though.

Comment: @Tranbi yes I will downgrade to 3.7, getting an error of future error "compatible dtype", but I see there are other posts about this. Thank you very much all.

Comment: adtk does not look to be actively maintained.  This was reported quite a while ago there: https://github.com/arundo/adtk/issues/152. Someone at that issue said they have a fork.