No module named 'matplotlib.backends.registry'
This question was updated, please read untill the end.
I started learning matplotlib with the Python Data Science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas that starts with this code for importing and setting style:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np

First, I got this error:
'seaborn-whitegrid' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in style.available)

I tried:
print(plt.style.available)

But the 'seaborn-whitegrid' was not listed. Then I went for updating packages:
pip install --upgrade matplotlib seaborn

Still it did not work. Now I get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2480, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2478     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2479 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2480     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2482 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2483 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2484 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2485 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py:103, in PylabMagics.matplotlib(self, line)
     98     print(
     99         "Available matplotlib backends: %s"
    100         % _list_matplotlib_backends_and_gui_loops()
    101     )
    102 else:
--> 103     gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
    104     self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3665, in InteractiveShell.enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3662     import matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
   3664 from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 3665 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   3667 if gui != None:
   3668     # If we have our first gui selection, store it
   3669     if self.pylab_gui_select is None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py:338, in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    321 def find_gui_and_backend(gui=None, gui_select=None):
    322     """Given a gui string return the gui and mpl backend.
    323 
    324     Parameters
   (...)
    335     'WXAgg','Qt4Agg','module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline','agg').
    336     """
--> 338     import matplotlib
    340     if _matplotlib_manages_backends():
    341         backend_registry = matplotlib.backends.registry.backend_registry

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:159
    155 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    157 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    158 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 159 from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
    160 from matplotlib.cbook import sanitize_sequence
    161 from matplotlib._api import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py:26
     23 import numpy as np
     25 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
---> 26 from matplotlib.backends import BackendFilter, backend_registry
     27 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper
     28 from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .registry import BackendFilter, backend_registry  # noqa: F401
      3 # NOTE: plt.switch_backend() (called at import time) will add a "backend"
      4 # attribute here for backcompat.
      5 _QT_FORCE_QT5_BINDING = False

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.registry'

Is this way of setting the style not valid anymore? Do I have to use:
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style='whitegrid') 

What else can I do?
Updating the progress:
After trying the recommended uninstall and reinstall, I got another error telling me it cannot uninstall:
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution ~atplotlib (C:\...\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages) 
Collecting matplotlib==3.10.0   
Using cached matplotlib-3.10.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB) 
Using cached matplotlib-3.10.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl (8.0 MB) 
Installing collected packages: matplotlib   
Attempting uninstall: matplotlib     
Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.10.0 error: uninstall-no-record-file  
× Cannot uninstall matplotlib 3.10.0 
╰─> The package's contents are unknown: no RECORD file was found for matplotlib. – 
    hint: You might be able to recover from this via: pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps matplotlib==3.10.0

But trying the offered command returns the same result!
I still do not know what to do with this. So I start with this import now:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

Again, it results in this long traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import seaborn as sns

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2480, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2478     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2479 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2480     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2482 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2483 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2484 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2485 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py:103, in PylabMagics.matplotlib(self, line)
     98     print(
     99         "Available matplotlib backends: %s"
    100         % _list_matplotlib_backends_and_gui_loops()
    101     )
    102 else:
--> 103     gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
    104     self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3665, in InteractiveShell.enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3662     import matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
   3664 from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 3665 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   3667 if gui != None:
   3668     # If we have our first gui selection, store it
   3669     if self.pylab_gui_select is None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py:338, in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    321 def find_gui_and_backend(gui=None, gui_select=None):
    322     """Given a gui string return the gui and mpl backend.
    323 
    324     Parameters
   (...)
    335     'WXAgg','Qt4Agg','module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline','agg').
    336     """
--> 338     import matplotlib
    340     if _matplotlib_manages_backends():
    341         backend_registry = matplotlib.backends.registry.backend_registry

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:159
    155 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    157 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    158 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 159 from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
    160 from matplotlib.cbook import sanitize_sequence
    161 from matplotlib._api import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py:26
     23 import numpy as np
     25 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
---> 26 from matplotlib.backends import BackendFilter, backend_registry
     27 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper
     28 from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .registry import BackendFilter, backend_registry  # noqa: F401
      3 # NOTE: plt.switch_backend() (called at import time) will add a "backend"
      4 # attribute here for backcompat.
      5 _QT_FORCE_QT5_BINDING = False

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.registry'

Then, by calling plt like this I get this other traceback telling me plt is not defined:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

Obviously the previous error didn't let it to be imported correctly, as the error implies:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 fig = plt.figure()
      2 ax = plt.axes()

NameError: name 'plt' is not defined


Obviously you will have to use a style from plt.style.available. I have a 'seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid' on my computer. Probably Matplotlib changed the style names since the book was published.

also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716259/the-seaborn-styles-shipped-by-matplotlib-are-deprecated-since-3-6

Now even checking the version ends up in the same error.  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.registry'

I see that you accepted an answer so your pb is solved?

@rehaqds  The answer gave me the correct code for seaborn style. But I still get warning and error.

Do you use a dedicated environment? do you work in Jupyter notebook? I see that you use Python 3.13, I would try with an older version. I don't know for Matplotlib but some libraries don't always work with the latest Python version.

@rehaqds For learning this library I am using Jupyter notebook. Should I backtrack to Python 3.12? I did reinstall matplotlib with pip install --user --ignore-installed --no-deps matplotlib==3.10.0 but I still get the No module named 'matplotlib.backends.registry' error.

Try using the new seaborn style naming convention with matplotlib:
plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid')

Or use seaborn's direct styling:
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")


The error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.registry' occurs when the matplotlib library is outdated, improperly installed, or there is a conflict between different versions of the library.So unistall matplotlib and reinstall it.
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib


Mine is working fine, screenshot attached.

Collecting matplotlib==3.10.0
  Using cached matplotlib-3.10.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Using cached matplotlib-3.10.0-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl (8.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
  Attempting uninstall: matplotlib
    Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.10.0
error: uninstall-no-record-file

× Cannot uninstall matplotlib 3.10.0
╰─> The package's contents are unknown: no RECORD file was found for matplotlib.```

I received the above warning and error when tried to uninstall. and it also suggested to:
hint: You might be able to recover from this via: pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps matplotlib==3.10.0   But trying the offered command turns the same result.

Delete all the files related to matplotlib manually, if you're unable to do it with pip.

The last thing I did was manually deleting all the residual files and remnanats from the previous installations. All the files named matplotlib, mpl_toolkits, ~atplotlib, or similar in the C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages folder had to go to restart with a clean slate. Then reinstall packages with:
pip install --upgrade ipython jupyter matplotlib

Now these work seamlessly:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()


I ran into this exact issue recently! The problem seems to be a combination of Python 3.13 (which is pretty new) and some changes in how matplotlib handles styles. Here's what worked for me:
First, I had to completely clean up my matplotlib installation because it was giving me those weird registry errors. This did the trick:
pip uninstall matplotlib seaborn
pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps matplotlib
pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps seaborn

After that, I found out that 'seaborn-whitegrid' style is actually deprecated now. The modern way to do this is:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# This is the new way to set the style
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Now you can create your plots normally
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

